# How can i show multiple columns of a table in a single column based on a column value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

[image: main table]
Now I want to write a query that can show these data as below:

[image: desire result]

How can I do this? Can anybody help me please?

Comment: This is better solved in your presentation layer... SQL-Server does not allow a resultset with *column groups*, which have something like a *meta-header*... You cannot use the same column name over and over,,, (at least if you want to use this resultset in any embedded context).

Comment: And **please!**: Do not insert pictures! If anybody wanted to help you, one had to type your data manually. Please read [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Shnugo thank you man. please eliminate headers and give me an answer if you know about my question. i just want data, not headers

Comment: You have two choices: 1) Call them `Pr1_AR  |  Pr1_SM1  | Pr1_SM2  | Pr2_AR ...` and use *conditional aggregation* or 2) combine all three values to one (e.g as XML like `<vals AR="0.1" SM1="0.2" SM2="0.3"/>`) and return them as one column called `Process1` and the next XML as `Process2` and so on... Please create the MCVE (see above) and state the expected output and what you've tried so far...

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT  Grade AS ISG,
            P1AR, P1SM1, P1SM2,
            P2AR, P2SM1, P2SM2,
            P3AR, P3SM1, P3SM2
    FROM 
    (
            SELECT  Grade, 
                    col = 'P' + CAST(Process AS NVARCHAR) +col,
                    value
            FROM    yourTable

            CROSS APPLY 
            (
                 VALUES
                 ('AR', AR),
                 ('SM1', SM1),
                 ('SM2', SM2)
            ) c(col, value)
     )  d
     PIVOT
     (
          MAX(value)
          FOR col IN (P1AR, P1SM1, P1SM2, 
                      P2AR, P2SM1, P2SM2,  
                      P3AR, P3SM1, P3SM2)
     ) piv
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to write this query is:

```
SELECT 
a.Grade AS ISG,
a.AR    AS P1AR,
a.SM1   AS P1SM1,
a.SM2   AS P1SM2,

b.AR    AS P2AR,
b.SM1   AS P2SM1,
b.SM2   AS P2SM2,

c.AR    AS P3AR,
c.SM1   AS P3SM1,
c.SM2   AS P3SM2    
FROM    yourTable a
INNER JOIN yourTable b
ON      a.Grade = b.Grade
INNER JOIN yourTable c
ON      a.Grade = c.Grade

where   a.Process = 1 and 
        b.Process = 2 and
        c.Process = 3
```